# My references doents show in Latex ( Visual Studio Code- VSCODE)

Tags: latex, runtime-error, bibtex

I was hopping maybe get your help for my problem. I use VSCODE to run latex but I dont Know why when i run my code, it seams to show always this error:

```
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'main.log' and/or above output for details
```

I think it has to do with my bib.

i get error in  this line in the main.tex :

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

My packages are :

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,doi=true, %display DOI with link
    eprint=false, %display arxiv id etc
    maxnames=25, %number of names in List of references
     maxcitenames=7, % number of names for textcite command
      ]{biblatex}
```

I have a propper bibliography.bib so I dont see wheres the error ?